# Push Notifications - Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, web, push-notification

I am working on a small project that involves a web interface that can send information to my android app which will display such information as Push Notifications.

But here is the thing, I am a bit confused with how to do that. As in what step will i have to take.

So I have a web interface in HTML which has a Textfield for notification Title, Content, and a submit button. I want it that when the user clicks the Submit button, the webpage will send the text that s in the Title and Content fields to my android app and then the app will just display them as push notifications.

So far on the app i have it that when you click a button on your device then it just shows a notification on the Actionbar. This is great for testing but It would be better that you can just compose your notification through a web interface.

My test Push Notification code for the app:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        // TODO: Make this accessible to exterior projects, such as web interface.
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTicker("Notification")
                .setContentTitle("Important Message")
                .setContentText("This is an example of a push notification using a Navigation Manager")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();

        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        nManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
});
```

If anyone could be so kind to give me a hand, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: web interface can use on desktop or only on mobile device

Comment: if it will run on mobile browser then u can search on 
<meta property="al:android:url" content = ""/>
in this approach you dont have to implement GCM

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32109581/4350275

Answer (score 2):

You are right, so far so good with the notification bar, now what you need is a notification service, and google has something like that for us...

[image]

## how does this works??

Take a look at  the image below,

you need to register your android app in the google service, and your web interface will need an id, so everytime you want to push something to the android, your web interface instead will push it to the google server with the Id of the app, then google (no matter how) will localize your app, and even if its not running, they will get the notification,

behind the scenes there is a couple of thing that you must do, bu nothing like launching rockets from the NASA.

I will suggest to take a look to some [tutorials](http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/)
in order to start with the registration of your app, get the api key etc etc..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great source in github which shows how you can add push notification service in your android app

github.com/rana01645/android-push-notification

Firstly read the full documentation

How to add push notification in android application from android studio – Android developer (part – 1 Connect with firebase ) ~ http://androidrace.com/2016/12/08/how-to-add-push-notification-in-android-application-from-android-studio-android-developer-part-1-connect-with-firebase/

How to add push notification in android application from android studio – Android developer (part – 2 Working with server) ~http://androidrace.com/2017/01/05/how-to-add-push-notification-in-android-application-from-android-studio-android-developer-part-2-working-with-server/

Then you can able to send push notification from your server using html

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Uyarilar extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        showNotification(context);
}

private void showNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.presta)
                    .setContentTitle("Saat 9:00")
                    .setContentText("Mesai saatiniz başlamıştır Lütfen harakete geçiniz!");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
}
```

and call

```
  private void setNotification() {
      Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
      Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
      calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
      calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
      calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
      if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
          calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
      }


             Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
             Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Uyarilar.class);
             PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
             AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


  }
```

and 
    onCreate
    setNotification();

Answer (score 1):

this method to push notification

```
public void testMessage (String message , Intent  intent){

 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    String channelId = "some_channel_id";
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setBadgeIconType(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```