# Inner request count exceeds the limit. Received: X, Limit: X

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php

```
    $push_input = [
        'data' => [
            'title' => 'PUSH MESSAGE TITLE',
            'subtext' => 'PUSH MESSAGE BODY'
        ]
    ];

    try {

        $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount('FILE PATH OF CREDENTIAL JSON'); // or use auto-loading of credentials
        
        $messaging = $factory->createMessaging();
        
        $message = CloudMessage::fromArray($push_input);
        
        $result = $messaging->sendMulticast($message, ['T1', 'T2',...,'T1000']);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        log_message('error', $e->getMessage());

    }
```

This is returns

> Inner request count exceeds the limit. Received: 985, Limit: 500

while it is working with 1000 tokens with this script https://stackoverflow.com/a/46235425/10585909

I have spent many days on google to find solution but didn't get it so need to create this question.

What is the issue, and how to resolve it?

Comment: There are a lot of variables whose values we can't see here.  Please edit the question in such a way that we can see everything in use here - hard code everything.  Also indicate which line of code generates the error.

Comment: @DougStevenson Question updated.

Comment: Which line of code generates the error?

Comment: While sending push `$result = $messaging->sendMulticast($message, ['T1', 'T2',...,'T1000']);` got the exception.

Comment: Do you think the error message has something to do with the number of items in that array?

Comment: Nope, it is working with https://stackoverflow.com/a/46235425/10585909 script but not working with firebase-php as same limit.
Also, I have changed the const variable in `vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Messaging/Http/Request/SendMessages.php` and `vendor/kreait/firebase-php/src/Firebase/Messaging/Http/Request/SendMessageToTokens.php` from 500 to 1000

Comment: OK, what do we have to do to replicate the issue?  Please give the **minimal complete code** to do so.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OK sure, i am trying to create reproducible example.

Comment: The reason is that your previous script uses the legacy FCM API, but the Firebase PHP SDK uses the HTTP V1 API, which has a limit of 500 tokens per batch request. The limits in the SDK code that you changed are there to avoid running into the error that you received after changing them ^^

Comment: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/498

Comment: Ok, Understand, thank you @jeromegamez