# Laravel API -Send Notifications to android and iOS client apps with Firebase FCM

Tags: laravel, firebase

I am working on a project which uses android and iOS as front and Backend as Laravel APIs.
So I want to send notifications to all users (include android/iOS) when some event happen like New Offer Created/New Stock available.. So to do this  is have gone through some google searches and finally knew that the curl approach seems to be deprecated.. so Is there any better Way to integrate firebase FCM into my Laravel project.. if it so How?
I hope someone can answer this..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM

Comment: Have you gone through it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fcm for core already answered here [How to send Notification to Android from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109239/how-to-send-notification-to-android-from-php/46235425#46235425)
so in laravel you can

create a `config file` in `config` folder and name it as `firebase.php`

```
 <?php

        return [
            'fcm_url'=>env('FCM_URL'),
            'fcm_api_key'=>env('FCM_API_KEY'),
        ];
```

and in env file

```
FCM_URL=https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
FCM_API_KEY=
```

and in code you can create Trait class

```
<?php


namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

trait Firebase
{

    public  function firebaseNotification($fcmNotification){

        $fcmUrl =config('firebase.fcm_url');

        $apiKey=config('firebase.fcm_api_key');

        $http=Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization:key'=>$apiKey,
            'Content-Type'=>'application/json'
        ])  ->post($fcmUrl,$fcmNotification);

        return  $http->json();
    }
}
```

Then you can include this trait any class where you want to call

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Traits\Firebase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use Firebase,AuthenticatesUsers;

    
    public function sendNotification(){
        $token="";
        $notification = [
            'title' =>'title',
            'body' => 'body of message.',
            'icon' =>'myIcon',
            'sound' => 'mySound'
        ];
        $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];

        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => $tokenList, //multple token array
            'to'        => $token, //single token
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];
        
        return $this->firebaseNotification($fcmNotification); 

    }
}
```

Also i suggest to create events based to better code optimization

Also read

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

**registration_ids** for multiple users

> This parameter specifies the recipient of a multicast message, a
> message sent to more than one registration token.
>
> The value should be an array of registration tokens to which to send
> the multicast message. The array must contain at least 1 and at most
> 1000 registration tokens. To send a message to a single device, use
> the to parameter.
>
> Multicast messages are only allowed using the HTTP JSON format.

For new Version as mentioned in comment by @JEJ

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#python_1

So it will be

```
  $http=Http::withHeaders([
                'Authorization'=>'Bearer '.$apiKey,
                'Content-Type'=>'application/json; UTF-8'
            ])  ->post($fcmUrl,$fcmNotification);
    
            return  $http->json();
```

and   simple notification message for `$fcmNotification`

```
{
  "message": {
    "topic": "news",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Breaking News",
      "body": "New news story available."
    },
    "data": {
      "story_id": "story_12345"
    }
  }
}
```

for targeting multiple platforms

```
{
  "message": {
    "topic": "news",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Breaking News",
      "body": "New news story available."
    },
    "data": {
      "story_id": "story_12345"
    },
    "android": {
      "notification": {
        "click_action": "TOP_STORY_ACTIVITY"
      }
    },
    "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if there is morethan 1000 registration tokens?

Comment: @jej you have to use chunk .for example if you have 5000 users in db and you can use chunk by 1000 .so inside loop you can call $this->firebaseNotification($fcmNotification)

Comment: yeah..Thanks @John

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1 need to change anthing to send group messages ?

Comment: @JEJ.i havent used fcm recently new changes.if  i get time later i will check it out

Comment: @JEJ.thanks for mentioning.if any issue with new version let me know i will check it out later and update post

Comment: "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234311/discussion-between-jej-and-john-lobo).

Answer (score 3):

Try **[Laravel FCM package](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM)**

For your ease, writing steps here...

**SETUP**

1. Installation (terminal)

   ```
   composer require brozot/laravel-fcm
   ```
2. config/app.php

   - providers

     ```
     'providers' => [
         // ...

         LaravelFCM\FCMServiceProvider::class,
     ]
     ```
   - aliases

     ```
     'aliases' => [
         ...

         'FCM'      => LaravelFCM\Facades\FCM::class,
     ]
     ```
3. Publish the package config file (terminal)

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="LaravelFCM\FCMServiceProvider"
   ```

---

**USAGE**

4. In your Controller,

   - import libraries

     ```
     use LaravelFCM\Message\OptionsBuilder;
     use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadDataBuilder;
     use LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder;
     use FCM;
     ```
   - sending Downstream Message to device(s)

     ```
     $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
     $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20);

     $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder('my title');
     $notificationBuilder->setBody('Hello world')->setSound('default');

     $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
     $dataBuilder->addData(['a_data' => 'my_data']);

     $option = $optionBuilder->build();
     $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
     $data = $dataBuilder->build();

     $token = "a_registration_from_your_database" /* OR */ [ /* Array of tokens */ ];

     $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, $notification, $data);

     $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess();
     $downstreamResponse->numberFailure();
     $downstreamResponse->numberModification();

     // return Array - you must remove all this tokens in your database
     $downstreamResponse->tokensToDelete();

     // return Array (key : oldToken, value : new token - you must change the token in your database)
     $downstreamResponse->tokensToModify();

     // return Array - you should try to resend the message to the tokens in the array
     $downstreamResponse->tokensToRetry();

     // return Array (key:token, value:error) - in production you should remove from your database the tokens
     $downstreamResponse->tokensWithError();
     ```