# How can I send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification to all devices in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to Firebase cloud messaging with Laravel,

Thanks to this code https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-firebase-push-notification-tutorialexample.html I was able to send notifications from my Firebase to my Android device by token using curl.

But, Is there any API or way to send a notification to all devices?

Comment: just answered similar question check it .it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68158865/laravel-api-send-notifications-to-android-and-ios-client-apps-with-firebase-fcm

Comment: There is no FCM API to send to all devices. The closest you can get is having all clients subscribe to a specific topic, and then sending to that topic. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38248296 (the accepted answer may look promising, but doesn't work anymore).